# How to override customerData folder's file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to override **`app/code/Magento/Checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php`** file. Becuase i have to change in this file. So how can i override this file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**registration.php file,**

filepath   `app/code/Package/Modulename/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Package_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

**module.xml** file,

filepath   `app/code/Package/Modulename/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Package_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`di.xml file`,
**filepath** `app/code/Package/Modulename/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem"
                 type="Package\Modulename\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
</config>
```

**DefaultItem.php file,**
**file path**, `app/code/Package/Modulename/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php`

```
<?php

namespace Package\Modulename\CustomerData;

class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{   
        //override function code here.....
}
```

you can change function code inside file function.

Comment: Sorry i have writed 1 module like this from you to fix the name in minicart but it's not working. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I have override one of file as below,

```
app/code/Namespace/Checkout/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

 <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
        <plugin name="checkout.cart.message" type="Namespace\Checkout\CustomerData\CartPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And then I have added customer data file in below path,

```
app/code/Namespace/Checkout/CustomerData/CartPlugin.php
```

In which my class is as below,

```
class CartPlugin extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart implements SectionSourceInterface
```

and its method is as below,

```
 public function aftergetSectionData()
    {.. my code goes here}
```

Same thing you can do with defaultItem file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use around or after plugin modify that file.

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem">
        <plugin name="starbucksb2b_add_attribute" type="NameSpace\Checkout\Plugin\DefaultItem" disabled="false" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

And since this is the only public function getItemData() (extends from AbstractItem) , create plugin for that and get the array, then reassign value using new function, eg create new function getProductUrl() in this file.

NameSpace/Checkout/Plugin/DefaultItem

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\Checkout\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

class DefaultItem
{
    const GROUP = 'grouped';

    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, \Closure $proceed, Item $item)
    {
        $data = $proceed($item);
        $product = $item->getProduct();

        if ($item->getProductType() == self::GROUP) {
            $data['product_url'] = $this->getUrl();
        }

        $atts = [
            'product_size' => $product->getAttributeText('st_size')
        ];

        return array_merge($data, $atts);
    }
    protect function getUrl(){
        return "test";
    }
```