# how to remove text "items" from top links wishlist magento 2

Tags: magento2, wishlist, toplinks

I want to display just wishlist count like wishlist (2) in top bar, how can I remove the word "items" or "item"

Comment: can you please upload your code here?

Answer (score 5):

You can override the phtml: `Theme_Root/Magento_Wishlist/templates/link.phtml`

Instead this:

```
<span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span>
```

You can do this:

```
<span data-bind="text: wishlist().items.length" class="counter qty"></span>
```

Comment: I'm wondering is it worked for you? For me its not working console generates error, but weird part is after reload page error disappear!!

Comment: Worked for me thanks.

Comment: Thanks @David It's working.

Comment: E.g I have 5 Items in wishlist after doing as you said, it shows me 3 items

Answer (score 3):

you can remove it from

if you have no theme installed you can go to this and change the 1 item and %1 items.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/i18n/en_US.csv  or

if you have a theme installed you can go to this location and do that.

> `app/design/frontend/Magento/<theme>/i18n/en_US.csv`

Comment: thanks! but if i change "%1 items" to "%1" in en_US.csv it will change every where it found "%1 items". is there any other way?

Comment: @waqar this is not used at more places so I think it will not affect your site. I personally replaced it and didn't see changes.You can go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

You can also edit counter generated phrase.

Look at the file in:

```
vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php
```

on line 84 you will see:

```
protected function createCounter($count)
{
    if ($count > 1) {
        return __('%1 items', $count);
    } elseif ($count == 1) {
        return __('1 item');
    }
    return null;
}
```

You only have to override that method in your custom module.

For more info on how to do that this, look the following:

[How to override customerData folder's file in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123512/how-to-override-customerdata-folders-file-in-magento-2)

Comment: Please correct the path in your answer. It's "CustomerData" folder.
/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento default way, just need to add simple regex for it.

Replace :

span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span

With :

span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')" class="counter qty"></span