# How to Override WishList Customer Data in magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin, wishlist, customer-data

i Want to Override

> Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist

```
public function getSectionData()
    {
        $counter = $this->getCounter();
        return [
            'counter' => $counter,
            'items' => $counter ? $this->getItems() : [],
        ];
    }
```

so in My `etc\frontend\di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist">
     <plugin name="wishlist" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Wishlist" disabled="false" sortOrder="0"/>
</type>
```

in My

> Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Wishlist

```
class Wishlist
{

    public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist $subject, $result)
    {
        return [
            'counter' => 2,
            'items' => NULL,
        ];

    }
}
```

when i apply plugin i am not getting any wishlist Array  in `mage-cache-storage`

Comment: What you want to do by override this file?

Comment: i want to make a guestwish list so i want data from cookie not from wishlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **aroundPlugin()** for get wishlist data from cookie.

**Step 1:** Create **di.xml** at this below path

> app/code/RH/CustomPlugin/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist">
        <plugin name="plugin_customer_data_wishlist" type="RH\CustomPlugin\Plugin\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create **Wishlist.php** at this below path

> app/code/RH/CustomPlugin/Plugin/Wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php

```
<?php

namespace RH\CustomPlugin\Plugin\Wishlist\CustomerData;

class Wishlist {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $wishlistHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $imageHelperFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface
     */
    protected $view;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar
     */
    protected $block;

    /**
     * Wishlist constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view
    ) {
        $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
        $this->imageHelperFactory = $imageHelperFactory;
        $this->block = $block;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function aroundGetSectionData(
        \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $counter = $this->getCounter();
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Rohan.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($counter);
        return [
            'counter' => $counter,
            'items' => $counter ? $this->getItems() : [],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getCounter() {
        return $this->createCounter($this->wishlistHelper->getItemCount());
    }

    /**
     * Create button label based on wishlist item quantity
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase|null
     */
    protected function createCounter($count) {
        if ($count > 1) {
            return __('%1 items', $count);
        } elseif ($count == 1) {
            return __('1 item');
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get wishlist items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getItems() {
        $this->view->loadLayout();

        $collection = $this->wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection();
        $collection->clear()->setInStockFilter(true)->setOrder('added_at');

        $items = [];
        foreach ($collection as $wishlistItem) {
            $items[] = $this->getItemData($wishlistItem);
        }
        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve wishlist item data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getItemData(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem) {
        $product = $wishlistItem->getProduct();
        return [
            'image' => $this->getImageData($product),
            'product_url' => $this->wishlistHelper->getProductUrl($wishlistItem),
            'product_name' => $product->getName(),
            'product_price' => $this->block->getProductPriceHtml(
                $product,
                'wishlist_configured_price',
                \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                ['item' => $wishlistItem]
            ),
            'product_is_saleable_and_visible' => $product->isSaleable() && $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_has_required_options' => $product->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($product),
            'add_to_cart_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getAddToCartParams($wishlistItem, true),
            'delete_item_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getRemoveParams($wishlistItem, true),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve product image data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function getImageData($product) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $helper */
        $helper = $this->imageHelperFactory->create()
            ->init($product, 'wishlist_sidebar_block');

        $template = $helper->getFrame()
        ? 'Magento_Catalog/product/image'
        : 'Magento_Catalog/product/image_with_borders';

        $imagesize = $helper->getResizedImageInfo();

        $width = $helper->getFrame()
        ? $helper->getWidth()
        : (!empty($imagesize[0]) ? $imagesize[0] : $helper->getWidth());

        $height = $helper->getFrame()
        ? $helper->getHeight()
        : (!empty($imagesize[1]) ? $imagesize[1] : $helper->getHeight());

        return [
            'template' => $template,
            'src' => $helper->getUrl(),
            'width' => $width,
            'height' => $height,
            'alt' => $helper->getLabel(),
        ];
    }
}
```

You can check it after create this plugin by add/remove wishlist item. My custom log will be generate from this custom plugin function.

**Hope, It will helpful for you.**

Answer (score 1):

Now need to override the CustomerData.Just Override the link.phtml file your theme.

```
<span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span>
```

You can do this:

```
<span data-bind="text: wishlist().items.length" class="counter qty"></span>
```

Hints : [how to remove text "items" from top links wishlist magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191373/how-to-remove-text-items-from-top-links-wishlist-magento-2)