# How to override magento-sales/CustomerData/LastOrderedItems.php?

Tags: magento2

I have created the following files below but it does not override the default LastOrderedItems.php file

Does anyone know what I have done wrong or should I have done this a different way?

app/code/MySite/ModuleSales/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Sales\CustomerData\LastOrderedItems"
                 type="MySite\ModuleSales\CustomerData\LastOrderedItems" />
</config>
```

app/code/MySite/ModuleSales/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MySite_ModuleSales" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/MySite/ModuleSales/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MySite_ModuleSales',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/MySite/ModuleSales/CustomerData/LastOrderedItems.php

```
<?php
namespace MySite\ModuleSales\CustomerData;

use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


class LastOrderedItems implements SectionSourceInterface
{
    protected function getItems() {
      ...code updates here
    }
}
```

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123512/how-to-override-customerdata-folders-file-in-magento-2 and same as you try magento-sales module

Comment: Thanks! I did follow that example but I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `getSectionData()`

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSectionData()
    {
        return ['items' => $this->getItems()];
    }
```

Since you don't extend original class, it won't work.

Also, you can move your DI preference to etc/frontend/di.xml since declaration for this class is placed there

```
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="last-ordered-items" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\CustomerData\LastOrderedItems</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```