# How to override module-wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist.php by using custom module?

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I have added custom code in m3\vendor\magento\module-wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist.php, and called inside the app\design\frontend\zero\my_theme\Magento_Wishlist\templates\sidebar.phtml, for testing i am directly edited in core files, how to properly Override by using custom module?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be the best option for you.

app/code/Vendor/Wishlist/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Wishlist_Plugin_Magento_Wishlist_CustomerData_Wishlist" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Wishlist\Plugin\Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/Vendor/Wishlist/Plugin/Magento/Wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Wishlist\Plugin\Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData;


class Wishlist
{

    protected $wishlistHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper
    )
    {
        $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
    }


    public function afterGetSectionData(
        \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        // Your code here

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i try to add the function: https://snipboard.io/XOK5Av.jpg inside the module.

Comment: I am trying to add the wholee function what i edit inside the C:\xampp\htdocs\m3\vendor\magento\module-wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist.php

Comment: Well you don't add it inside a function you would add it after the afterGetSectionData function

Comment: Also you cannot overwrite a protected function you would need to do you modifications in the afterGetSectionData function

Comment: I am getting confused, 1) should i add the function which i edit in the core wishlist.php after the afterGetSectionData right? ( code : https://codeshare.io/anxjMV )

Comment: No the function you have written cannot be overwritten can you give me more insight into what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122825/discussion-between-zus-and-dava-gordon).

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/123518/92172